# any website tracking history of circulating tokens of any coin?

Tags: history, raw-data

Is there any website dedicated to tracking history of circulating tokens of any coin?

Ideally, for each time a crypto has tokens added or removed to its circulating amount, we'd want to know:

- amount
- exact date
- sent to whom (even if burnt, we want the address)

I am currently writing an analysis about many different coins and found this information incredibly hard to get (in most cases).

Token distribution is the base so I would expect a website or sort of organization dedicated to this task, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look on blockchain.info, you can type in the block number to bring up [this page for block# 510223](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000001e9507da8e369835974ea2ab717228c4fe70f310373543) for example.

In that block, the first transaction is the coinbase transaction for the block reward (No Inputs (Newly Generated Coins)) and the output is the recipient address.

Note that you should wait until a block has six confirmations before you consider it final (is buried under six additional blocks).